# In Objective C how to change view on localNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, localnotification

I need to take the user on a specific view (nib) after he click on the button of localNotification: the iPhone play the sound of the notification... the user click on the button... the app come up with the last view he visited... I want to change that view and take the user to another view...
Is there a way to do that?
Thanks for any help. Massy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user click the local notification, an AppDelegate method is called :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

You simply have to implement this method in your appDelegate an do whatever you want.

PS : Note that another method is available since iOS8 :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
```

Comment: I know that method but it doesn't accept [self presentViewController:myView animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: `self` is referring to `AppDelegate` and `AppDelegate` is not a `UIViewController`. What you have to do is to access to your main view controller or your current view controller (using an AppDelegate `property` or an Observer) and ask him to present the view controller you want to show.